# Check if columns exist and if not, create and fill with NaN using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe and a separate list of column names. I want to check and see if any of the list column  names are missing, and if they are, I want to create them and fill with null values.

Is there a straightforward way to do this in pyspark? I can do it in Pandas, but it's not what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
 if 'col' not in df.schema.names:
    df = df.withColumn('col', F.lit(None).cast(StringType())
```

Let me know if you face any issue.